# Python requests POST method unexpected content in response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am tring to get the EPG data at the web page `https://www.meo.pt/tv/canais-programacao/guia-tv` using Python requests. I use this module a lot, but mainly the `GET` method. This request however is using `POST`. Everytime you scroll down the page, a request is sent to the API below using these params to load additional program data to the page:

```
import requests

#post request
url = 'https://www.meo.pt/_layouts/15/Ptsi.Isites.GridTv/GridTvMng.asmx/getProgramsFromChannels'

headers = {
'Accept': '*/*',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '214',
'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
'Host': 'www.meo.pt',
'Origin': 'https://www.meo.pt',
'Referer': 'https://www.meo.pt/tv/canais-programacao/guia-tv',
'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36',
'X-KL-Ajax-Request': 'Ajax_Request'
}


data = {"service":"channelsguide",
"channels":["LVTV","TOROTV","CAÇAP","CAÇAV","RTPACRS","CLUBB","MCM T","TRACE","24KITC","E!"],
"dateStart":"2021-04-20T23:00:00.000Z",
"dateEnd":"2021-04-21T23:00:00.000Z",
"accountID":""}


r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(r.text)
```

I have tried this request, both with and without the headers used, as I don't know if they are needed for a `POST` request. However, both these options don't return what i was expecting, which was a JSON object containing the program data for these channels.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `json` argument instead of `data` in request function. The `json` argument parses your body to JSON format while `data` you are sending a raw dictionary.

```
data = {"service":"channelsguide",
"channels":["LVTV","TOROTV","CAÇAP","CAÇAV","RTPACRS","CLUBB","MCM T","TRACE","24KITC","E!"],
"dateStart":"2021-04-20T23:00:00.000Z",
"dateEnd":"2021-04-21T23:00:00.000Z",
"accountID":""}


r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

If you want to keep using `data` argument you should parse data dictionary to JSON to send the correct body format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example how to POST json data to the API Url:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.meo.pt/_layouts/15/Ptsi.Isites.GridTv/GridTvMng.asmx/getProgramsFromChannels"

payload = {
    "accountID": "",
    "channels": [
        "SCPHD",
        "EURHD",
        "EURS2HD",
        "DISNY",
        "CART",
        "BIGGS",
        "SICK",
        "NICKELO",
        "DISNYJ",
        "PANDA",
    ],
    "dateEnd": "2021-04-21T22:00:00.000Z",
    "dateStart": "2021-04-20T22:00:00.000Z",
    "service": "channelsguide",
}

data = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()

# pretty print the data:    
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "d": {
        "__type": "Ptsi.Isites.GridTv.CanaisService.GridTV",
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "services": [],
        "channels": [
            {
                "__type": "Ptsi.Isites.GridTv.CanaisService.Channels",
                "ExtensionData": {},
                "id": 36,
                "name": "SPORTING TV HD",
                "sigla": "SCPHD",
                "friendlyUrlName": "Sporting_TV_HD",
                "url": "https://meogo.meo.pt/direto?canalUrl=Sporting_TV_HD",
                "meogo": true,
                "logo": "https://www.meo.pt/PublishingImages/canais/sporting-tv-hd.png",
                "isAdult": false,
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "ExtensionData": {},
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Desporto"
                    }
                ],

...
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to keep using data argument you should parse data
> dictionary to JSON to send the correct body format.

And you should set **headers** as:

```
headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
```

complete code is:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://www.meo.pt/_layouts/15/Ptsi.Isites.GridTv/GridTvMng.asmx/getProgramsFromChannels"

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}

payload = {
    "accountID": "",
    "channels": [
        "SCPHD",
        "EURHD",
        "EURS2HD",
        "DISNY",
        "CART",
        "BIGGS",
        "SICK",
        "NICKELO",
        "DISNYJ",
        "PANDA",
    ],
    "dateEnd": "2021-04-21T22:00:00.000Z",
    "dateStart": "2021-04-20T22:00:00.000Z",
    "service": "channelsguide",
}

resp = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=json.dumps(payload))
print(resp.text)
```